# Java. Swing. Absolute position

Tags: java, swing, css-position

I need to set component's location in a window.
I need to draw component on a `GlassPane` near another component, which was clicked. I pass the component, which raises click event to some manager, there I want to get coordinates where to paint.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                ApplicationManager.getInstance().drawOnGlassPane((Component e.getSource());
            }

public void drawOnGlassPane(final Component caller) {

        mainFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(caller);
        JPanel glassPane = (JPanel) mainFrame.getGlassPane();
        glassPane.setVisible(true);

        Point where = caller.getLocationOnScreen();
        JButton btn = new JButton("on glass pane");
        btn.setBounds((int) where.getX(), (int) (where.getY() + caller.getHeight()), 50, 20);
        glassPane.add(btn);
    }
}
```

The new component appears in a wrong place. How could I set correct location?

Comment: Have you tried using every single layout manager and decided that none of them can do what you want?

Comment: Ok, I must have custom dialogs painted in the diffirent places(depending on caller's current location). I can't think of the appropriate layout manager that can lay out in its own container connected to the location of components in other independent container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this question is described including example in the tutorial about [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), another example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1320__JRootPane.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1321__GlassPane.htm)